# Max Character Per line in a textbox in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox

I have a textbox and i want that it should have only 21 characters at max and they should be displayed in 3 lines(7 characters in each). As the user is typing when he types the 7th character i want the focus to be shifted to next line. I have already tried the following code

```
int textLength = a.Text.Length;
if (textLength % 8 == 0)
{
    a.Text += "\n";
    a.SelectionStart = a.Text.Length - 1;
}
```

It does not work . 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Where did you put that code?

Comment: What would be the behavior if I manually go back from line 2 to line 1 and delete one character and then add another? What you try above creates another line when there already is one...

Comment: i put that code in the keydown event of the textbox . if you manually go and delete then the first line will have 6 and the below lines would be 7 and 7

Comment: Your code is working fine. I have tested and it work as you expected.

Comment: @hardyz009 Yes, but what if I delete and then add a new character? Your code will add a new line - then you have 4 lines